# Left shift invariant ergodic measures not supported on a periodic orbit

Tags: real-analysis, ergodic-theory

Given $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ with left shift $\phi$, product topology and Borel algebra, it's easy to verify that there is an ergodic probability measure corresponding to each probability vector $(p, q)$ and to each periodic orbit of the left shift. Are there any other ergodic measures that are (relatively) simple to describe? I've seen a few constructions with some really horrible looking conditional measure stuff that I didn't really follow. References are welcome as well!

Comment: Are the examples that are supported on union of finite periodic orbits or countable orbits satisfy your needs?

Comment: How would one define an ergoic measure on a countable orbit?

Comment: If you have a sequence of invariant measure $\{\mu_i\}$, then the measure $\mu=\sum\frac{1}{2^i}\mu_i$ is also an invariant measure.

Comment: It need not be ergodic though

Comment: In fact a convex combination of ergodic measures isn't ergodic

Comment: Sorry I did not see the word ergodic, let me think another example.

Comment: You can take a subshift, with an ergodic measure, then this induces a ergodic measure of full shift.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I know an ergodic measure exists on each subshift from the Kryloff-Bogoliouboff argument, but I've never worked concretely with these.